# remote desktop application with transparent desktop?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, lan, seamless

i'm looking for a remote desktop application with transparent desktop ,
i mean where only all open windows will be visible seamelessly , like
the unity mode in vmware for example or the cohenrent disply in parralel desktop . 
I have try absolutly all remote app in the wiki , and i never find this option , so is there a technical reason or is it a big lake ?

regrds

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for RemoteApp, a feature of remote desktop where upon connecting to a remote desktop server, only one app is transmitted rather than the entire desktop environment.

The server needs to support it, but the client can just use a modified .rdp file.

Given the lack of information to where the server is, I can't provide more detail than this, but googling for RemoteApp will provide you with all the requirements on the server.

Comment: i try something .. the server is a local home lan , i want to run the same app between 2 users . its like a classic remote desktop but we only see the windows 'transparency'  . With remoteApp i only manged to execute a remote app , its different than remote control because remote control allow 2 users to retake control of the mouse/keyboard